# Creating LineString geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, linestring

The default geometry type for a newly created line seems to be `MultiLineString`.  It can be changed to `LineString` using the "Multipart to Singleparts" tool while saving in memory. However, once it is exported it saves as `MultiLineString`.

Is there a way to create a line *.shp* as `LineString`?

I am using QGIS 3.2.2 Bonn on Mac os X 10.13.6.

Comment: what are you exporting it as? Shapefiles don't distinguish between single and multis so are always reported as Multi for safety.

Comment: That might explain it....I was exporting as a shapefile.  Will try something else and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: alternatively, while in any way, when exporting to *.shp is a tool that does not work yet, maybe it will be improved in future versions...the main thing to reach out to the developers...

Comment: @Ian Turton, the problem was with the shapefile.  QGIS3 saves exported shapefiles as a multilinestring.  I got around this by using the geopackage. Although, will be building contingencies for multilinestrings into the QGIS3 plugin.  Thanks for the help!

I will reach out to QGIS with this comment.  Maybe the user can designate type during creation?

Comment: No, shapefiles are always multilinestrings because they are old and stupid.

Comment: I have run into the same problem and exporting as `.gpkg` did not resolve the issue either. When exporting, I selected `linestring` and did not check the box `Force multi`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the issue of the last comment. A new GeoPackage layer that is created as linestring remained a linestring layer for me when I edited a new feature and saved the layer. I tested by removing the layer from the QGIS project and then re-opening it. My QGIS version is 3.35.

[image]